# Iterative exponentiation process

Tags: lisp, scheme

From SICP's 1.24: ([Exponentiation](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html))

(you may need to click through and read ~1 page to understand)

> Exercise 1.16.  Design a procedure
>   that evolves an iterative
>   exponentiation process that uses
>   successive squaring and uses a
>   logarithmic number of steps, as does
>   fast-expt. (Hint: Using the
>   observation that (*b*<sup>*n*/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = (*b*<sup>2</sup>)<sup>*n*/2</sup>,
>   keep, along with the exponent *n* and
>   the base *b*, an additional state
>   variable *a*, and define the state
>   transformation in such a way that the
>   product *a b<sup>n</sup>* is unchanged from state
>   to state. At the beginning of the
>   process *a* is taken to be 1, and the
>   answer is given by the value of *a* at
>   the end of the process. In general,
>   the technique of defining an invariant
>   quantity that remains unchanged from
>   state to state is a powerful way to
>   think about the design of iterative
>   algorithms.)

I wrote the following solution:

```
(define (even n) (= (remainder n 2) 0))

(define (fast-expt b n)
  (fast-expt-iter b b n))

(define (fast-expt-iter a b n)
  (cond ((= n 1) a)
    ((even n) (fast-expt-iter (* a b) b (/ n 2)))
    (else (fast-expt-iter (* a b) b (- n 1)))))
```

Do you think my solution is correct?  Moreover, what do you think about my code?

Comment: `even?` is a Scheme builtin, so you should not define your own version. :-) Also, your bottom version isn't iterative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation will not produce correct results in general because your recursive definitions are erroneous.

One should note that in case n = 0, result is 1.  In case of even n (or n = 2 i), one may write b ^ n = (b * b) ^ i.  In case of odd n (or n = 2 i + 1), one may write b ^ n = b * (b * b) ^ i.  Here's an implementation (using if's instead of cond and folding the two recursive steps into one):

```
(define (fast-expt b n)
  (if (= n 0) 1
      (* (if (= (remainder n 2) 0) 1 b) (fast-expt (* b b) (quotient n 2)))))
```

To make this definition iterative, use the accumulator, a, that is initially 1.  When n is even (n = 2 i), square b but keep a unchanged.  This maintains the property b ^ n = a * (b ^ 2) ^ i.  When n is odd (n = 2 i + 1), square b and multiply a by b.  This maintains the property b ^ n = (a * b) * (b ^ 2) ^ i.  Thus, we have:

```
(define (fast-expt b n)
  (fast-expt-iter 1 b n))

(define (fast-expt-iter a b n)
  (if (= n 0) a
      (fast-expt-iter (* a (if (= (remainder n 2) 0) 1 b)) (* b b) (quotient n 2))))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for (fast-expt 2 2) - it returns 2, which should be 4, shouldn't it?

Comment: @jaresty:  You're absolutely right.  I screwed up my recursive definition. =)  I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Hmm... I'm a bit confused.  The problem asked for an "iterative solution," but I feel like the solution we arrived at is somehow more recursive than iterative.  What do you think?

Comment: @jaresty:  Agreed.  I forgot to include the iterative version.  Edited it into the answer.